# Trying to rename multiple files name with .bat script

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to rename multiple file name with a .bat file but i dont seem to be able to. The file name look like this at the beginning error_Link_4313.xml3531675 and it need to  be rename to: Link_4313.xml. Can somebody help me resolve this? Basicly i need to remove the 'error_' at the beginning of the file and the number after the '.xml'

Comment: Read [Ask], and [MCVE]. If you just have one file to rename, what do you need the batch file for?

Comment: You can use the `SET` command to create a substring of the variable.  To see that syntax open up a cmd prompt and type: `set /?`

Comment: Easy! `@Ren "error_Link_4313.xml3531675*" "Link_4313.xml"`

Comment: I want to do it dynamically. I need to remove the "error_" at the beginning of the fille and the number after the ".xml"

Comment: Your question title and body was specific to singular 'file name'. If you are now suggesting that your intention was to rename multiple files which have naming structures similar to `error_Link_4313.xml3531675` then you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49183247/edit) accordingly. Whilst you're at it please provide the code you've tried and failed to get to work, otherwise your question is an off-topic code request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two examples for you, which are designed to run with the files location as their working directories.

From the Command prompt:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %A In ('Where .:error_Link_*.xml*') Do @For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=_" %B In ("%A") Do @Ren "%A" "%~nC.xml"
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Where .:error_Link_*.xml*'
) Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=_" %%B In ("%%A") Do Ren "%%A" "%%~nC.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you so much! And sorry if my question wasnt clear enought, pretty new on stackoverflow!